# Why doesn't XAMPP work when it's not in the root of a partition?

Tags: windows, xampp

I've been having an issue lately. My XAMPP folder used to be on C:, right at the very top, but I want the XAMPP folder to be located somewhere else. The problem is, if I do that, I can't start up Apache or MySQL. It works completely fine as long as XAMPP is at C:/xampp/, but as soon as I move it anywhere else that is not at the very top of the given partition, it no longer works. The error log is also not very helpful.

The version I'm using is 7.4.6 on Windows, specifically the portable version (xampp-portable-windows-x64-7.4.6-0-VC15). Is this some sort of quirk from the portable version? Or do I need to change some settings to make it work on other folders?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The same thing happens when I installed XAMPP in ubuntu 20.04, the solution to this issue is by creating a symbolic link to connect the root directory C:/xampp/ with a target directory you choose or create.

Here is a useful link to create symbolic links in Windows.
[symbolic_links_windows](https://www.howtogeek.com/howto/16226/complete-guide-to-symbolic-links-symlinks-on-windows-or-linux/)

Comment: Thanks, I'll give it a try when I'm back home. Would that also work if your XAMPP directory is on a USB stick?